# Hint text in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, formatting, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

In LWUIT, some components (like the textField) have a hint property. Is there anyway to change this text´s format?

I need to modify font and color. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah its possible. Hint UIID name is `TextHint`. So you can use Component name as `TextHint` on Unselected style on ResourceEdit file.

Answer (score 0):

TextField font and color changes code:

```
txtName.getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_MONOSPACE, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
txtName.getStyle().setFgColor(0XFFAA00);
```